# split the string using regex when there is no delimeters using java

Tags: java

I have a string eg : `DIGITAL SPORTS$8.95HD AO$9.95UCC REC$1.28RENTAL FEE$7.00LOCAL FRANCHISE$4.67`
Now I want to split the string and create a map as

```
DIGITAL SPORTS $8.95 
HD AO $9.95
UCC REC $1.28
RENTAL FEE $7.00
LOCAL FRANCHISE $4.67
```

I wrote a regular expression to split the string. Please find below piece of code

```
private static String ledgerString = "DIGITAL SPORTS$8.95HD AO$9.95UCC REC$1.28RENTAL FEE$7.00LOCAL FRANCHISE$4.67";
private static Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("([[a-zA-Z ]*\\$[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]]*)");
private static Matcher matcher = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    matcher = pattern1.matcher(ledgerString.trim());

    if (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    } 

}
```

could you please some one help me how to extract the data from the above string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static String ledgerString = "DIGITAL SPORTS$8.95HD AO$9.95UCC REC$1.28RENTAL FEE$7.00LOCAL FRANCHISE$4.67";
private static Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z ]+)(\\$[0-9]*\\.[0-9][0-9])");
private static Matcher matcher = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    matcher = pattern1.matcher(ledgerString.trim());

    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern in group 1 is in character class `[...]` which is probably now that you ware trying to do. Maybe change your pattern to

```
Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z ]*)(\\$[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*)");
```

and use it like this

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+" "+matcher.group(2));
}
```

---

Also since Java7 you can name groups `(?<name>...)` so this is also possible

```
Pattern.compile("(?<name>[a-zA-Z ]*)(?<price>\\$[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*)");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group("name")+" "+matcher.group("price"));
}
```

---

Output

```
DIGITAL SPORTS $8.95
HD AO $9.95
UCC REC $1.28
RENTAL FEE $7.00
LOCAL FRANCHISE $4.67
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
The Regex:    (?:(.+?)(\$\d*(?:\.\d+)?))

String regex = "(?:(.+?)(\\$\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?))";
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/bkpb6)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could replace all occurrences of the "$" symbol with ",$" (comma dollar) symbol. After which you may split it using "," (comma). Do something like:

```
ledgerString = ledgerString.replaceAll("$", ",$");
String[] tokens = ledgerString.split(",");
```

Comment: in this case all the keys (DIGITAL SPORTS, HD AO, etc.) would be at the odd indices, while the cost in dollars would be stored at the even indices. you can already store it in a map from there...

Comment: no, after the first element all the rest would be like '$8.95 name of next product'

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want to use is one that matches each String that you are interested in. Therefore you want to use

Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]*\$[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9])");

as this identifies each 'line' you're interested in. You can then use split("$") on each line to separate description from price.

Answer (score 0):

Here is, yet another way of doing that:

```
 String mainString = "DIGITAL SPORTS$8.95HD AO$9.95UCC REC$1.28RENTAL FEE$7.00LOCAL FRANCHISE$4.67";

     String[] splittedArray = mainString.split("[0-9][A-Z]");
    int currentLength = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < splittedArray.length; i++) {
       String splitedString;

        if(i == 0) {
            char endChar = mainString.charAt(splittedArray[i].length());
            splitedString =  splittedArray[i] + endChar;
            currentLength += splittedArray[i].length();
        }
        else if(i == splittedArray.length -1){
           char beginChar = mainString.charAt(currentLength + 1);
            splitedString = beginChar + splittedArray[i];
        }
        else {
           char beginChar = mainString.charAt(currentLength + 1);
           char endChar = mainString.charAt(currentLength+splittedArray[i].length()+2);
           splitedString = beginChar + splittedArray[i] + endChar;
            currentLength += splittedArray[i].length()+2;
        }
         System.out.println(splitedString);
    }
```